# Identify parts of the sentence in "What day is it today?"

Tags: sentence-construction

Could you identify parts of the sentence in "What day is it today?"

I mean: subject, object, predicate and others.

Comment: Seems like homework. What are your thoughts?

Comment: No, it is not...

Answer (score 1):

The related statement:

> It is Monday today

Has structure Subject verb complement adverb-of-time

Inverted in the question:

> [What day] is it today?

Complement verb subject adverb-of-time.

Compare with:

> What character am I today?

and see that the subject pronoun "I" is used, not "me"